# Remove extraneous data from excel file with python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am given an excel spreadsheet with data that needs to analyzed using python pandas. However, the data is formatted in a way where it cannot be directly converted to a pandas dataframe. The spreadsheet includes descriptions in the first few lines, followed by the data that needs to be analyzed. For Example, a spreadsheet may look like this: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ifHL.png)

```
This csv document is not the official valuation. This has been provided to you at your request for your convenience only.                                       
Please refer to the accompanying PDF document for the official valuation statement. "                                       
                                        
For: Company XYZ                                        
                                        
                                                                                                                      Mark to Market    
                                                                                                                          Your Favor    
                                                                           Fixed    Fixed                                (Our Favor)    
  Deal                   Deal   Reference            Start                 Price    Price   Deal         Remaining     Present Value    
  Id                     Date   Commodity            Date       Expiry    Strike     Curr   Type          Quantity               USD        
  ------------------    ------- ----------------    -------     ------- --------    -----   ----    --------------  ----------------        
                                        
                                                                                
Valuations and position directions are from the client point of view                                        
Notice: The information in this document is confidential.
```

I need to manipulate the spreadsheet in a way where I can isolate the data that needs to be analyzed. I cannot use the skip rows method with read_excel because the number of rows of text can vary betweeen documents. I also cannot pre-process the document because this process will be automated.

Any suggestions will help

Comment: When it comes to spreadsheets, to avoid ambiguity, you must provide a precise description (*always better with a screenshot showing the headings*) and not a plain text. Are the header/footer notes stored in a single cell or can they be spread in multiple rows and/or columns ? Also, you say nothing about the number/names of columns ? Are they the same for all files ?

Comment: @Timeless I have provided an example image from excel. It includes the exact format the file will come in excluding the actual data. The columns are the same for all files, the only difference is the amount of rows the notes may take up it may be more or less.

Comment: Thanks for amending. It seems like your file is a `*.csv` that you opened in Excel. Is it the case ?

Comment: @Timeless yes that is the case

Comment: If you can open the csv file (*shown in the picture*) in a text editor (*like Notepad*) and copy/paste as plain text it in your post, that would be helpful.

Comment: @Timeless There you go

Comment: Side note: Excel and CSV are not synonyms.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you have a block (*of [fixed-width](https://www.softinterface.com/Convert-XLS/Features/Fixed-Width-Text-File-Definition.htm) data*) that is delimited between at least two empty lines. If it's always the case, you can [`split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split) the data, then [`read_fwf`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_fwf.html) to make your dataframe :

```
import re
from io import StringIO

with open("file.csv") as f:
    data = re.split(r"^\s+\n\s+?", f.read(), flags=re.M)[1]
    raw = pd.read_fwf(StringIO(data), header=None, comment="-")

N = 5 # the height of the header (columns names)

cols = raw.iloc[:5].fillna("").apply(lambda s: s.str.cat(sep=" ").strip())

df = raw.iloc[5:].set_axis(cols, axis=1)
```

Output (*0 rows x 10 columns*) :

| Deal Id | Deal Date | Reference Commodity | Start Date | Expiry | Fixed Price Strike | Fixed Price Curr | Deal Type | Remaining Quantity | Mark to Market Your Favor (Our Favor) Present Value USD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

Comment: This did not work for me. It grouped the first 3 columns together as well as the 5 6 7 cols together. The 4th column and the last 3 columns were correct though, so the solution isn't completely wrong. It also doesn't take care of the notes at the bottom of the sheet

Comment: Sorry but I can't imagine how exactly your real data look like. With the provided example, the code actually **works** as expected. Anyways, your question became a *moving target* from the moment you failed to provide a meaningful mockup of your data. So, IMHO, there won't be an answer that might satisfy you. And considering the 4-day delay in your response, it doesn't seem that it's a top priority for you. Good luck though ;)